Segmentation fault when using 'triangle' library ONLY when processing multiple geometries in loop
I am trying to process shapely polygon geometries and decompose them into triangles with the constraint that triangle vertices can only exist on the polygon edge(s).
For some strange reason the code works most of the time, but then I have a specific polygon, that results in a segmentation fault

(Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal
11:SIGSEGV): POLYGON ((545155.9709965222 5378933.039350484,
545155.8786686319 5378932.570194424, 545153.9828366871 5378934.823291995, 545154.3704756413 5378934.7733652275, 545155.9709965222 5378933.039350484))

and this ONLY when I run the code for the entire geodataframe containing all geometries to be triangulated.
I am at a loss what the issue is, since it works if I execute the code line by line for this specific polygon, but keeps crashing if run within my loop.
I am running python 3.12 and use triangle library version 20230923.
Also, if someone has a workaround in python I would be very grateful! Unfortunately, the shapely triangulation does not have any constraints as far as I understand, so I cannot use it for my purpose.
My code:
import os
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, MultiPolygon, Polygon, GeometryCollection
from shapely.validation import explain_validity
import shapely.geometry as geom
import numpy as np
import triangle as tr


def is_triangle(geometry):
    if isinstance(geometry, Polygon):
        # For a single Polygon, check if it has 3 vertices
        return len(list(geometry.exterior.coords)) == 4  # 4 because the last point is the same as the first (closed polygon)
    elif isinstance(geometry, MultiPolygon):
        # For MultiPolygon, check if each polygon is a triangle
        return all(len(list(poly.exterior.coords)) == 4 for poly in geometry.geoms)
    else:
        return False  # In case of unexpected geometry types


def process_geometry(geometry):
    # Check if the geometry is valid
    if not geometry.is_valid:
        print(f"Invalid geometry: {explain_validity(geometry)}")
        geometry = geometry.buffer(0)  # Try fixing the geometry by buffering with 0

    if is_triangle(geometry):
        return [geometry]  # Return as a list for consistency
    elif isinstance(geometry, Polygon):
        return triangulate_polygon(geometry)  # Triangulate and return the list of triangles
    elif isinstance(geometry, MultiPolygon):
        triangles = []
        for poly in geometry.geoms:
            triangles.extend(triangulate_polygon(poly))  # Triangulate each part of the MultiPolygon
        return triangles
    else:
        raise ValueError("Geometry type not supported")

def triangulate_polygon(geometry):
    # Remove near-duplicate vertices to prevent errors caused by floating-point precision issues:
    cleaned_coords = remove_near_duplicate_vertices(np.array(geometry.exterior.coords))
    polygon = Polygon(cleaned_coords)

    coords = np.array(polygon.exterior.coords)
    # coords = np.array(geometry.exterior.coords)

    # Check for Degenerate or Collinear Segments
    for i in range(len(coords) - 1):
        dist = np.linalg.norm(coords[i] - coords[i + 1])
        if dist < 1e-8:  # Check if distance is too small
            print(f"Nearly degenerate segment between points {i} and {i + 1}")

    # Make sure there are enough unique points for triangulation
    if len(coords) < 3:
        return []
    segments = [[i, (i + 1) % len(coords)] for i in range(len(coords) - 1)]

    # Ensure that no index is out of bounds
    for segment in segments:
        if any(idx >= len(coords) for idx in segment):
            print(f"Invalid segment index {segment}")



    # Perform triangulation using the triangle library
    triangulation = tr.triangulate({'vertices': coords, 'segments': segments}, 'p')

    triangles = create_triangles_from_triangulation(triangulation)

    return triangles


def create_triangles_from_triangulation(triangulation):
    """Convert the triangulation output into Shapely Polygon objects."""
    triangles = []
    if 'triangles' in triangulation:
        coords = triangulation['vertices']
        for tri_indices in triangulation['triangles']:
            triangle_coords = coords[tri_indices]
            triangles.append(geom.Polygon(triangle_coords))
    return triangles



all_triangles = []

    for id, tri in non_triangles_gdf.iterrows():
        print(tri)
        print(id)
        print(tri['geometry'])
        geom = tri['geometry']
        all_triangles.extend(process_geometry(geom))


This is not really a minimal, reproducible, example. It doesn't seem very minimal (do you really need all this pre-processing to create this error?) and it's not reproducible (we don't have non_triangles_gdf). You're more likely to get a helpful reply if you can create some sample data that recreates the problem in less code.  Having said that, given this only occurs when you run it in the loop suggests some sort of state-related problem. Perhaps add some manual garbage collection in your loop?

@SamR thx for your comment. How can I provide my non_triangles_gdf? Sry, I am new to this ... And yes, it's not minimal, but I added a ton of checking routines to make sure, the polygon geometry is valid. I guess this is not necessary.

Rather than providing your entire data frame, the best thing is usually to generate some data in the code at the start of the question e.g. here. That might be difficult in your case. Have you worked out how many rows you need before you generate this error?

It crashes at exactly dataset row 474. If I delete this polygon dataset, then it runs until row 2878 and throws the same error. I had this error before, when there were some nans present. But I exported the geodataframe , looked at it in QGIS, the data is fine, the polygon is valid, it is not a sliver polygon , has no short segments or anything. So it is really mysterious to me and I cannot debug because I have no idea where to look. I also ran it on another machine and exact same polygon crashes the code. So I am guessing there MUST be a problem with the geometry, but what could it be?

to add to my previous comment - regarding the fact that the code DOES run when executed line by line manually using just the "problematic" polygon makes the entire behavior even more mysterious to me

What happens if you run this on non_triangles_gdf[473:476]? If it doesn't crash that would indicate that the problem is something to do with low-level memory management. If it does it would suggest it's something in your code that is different when you pass an iterable compared with when you pass individual objects.

running just the slice of the gdf crashes at the same polygon 474. I also just tried running first row 473 manually, which worked no problem and then 474, which DID NOT work! so also not manually this time. could it in fact be some sort of variable blocking or something along the line of your first comment regarding garbage collection? This is the step where 474 crashes the code

tr.triangulate({'vertices': coords, 'segments': segments}, 'p')
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11:SIGSEGV)


Tried another version, using "simple" triangulation without any options:

triangulation = tr.triangulate(input_triangles)

Error during triangulation: Out of bounds on buffer access (axis 0)
Vertices: [[ 540684.54023738 5375881.69439712]
[ 540687.         5375876.81      ]
[ 540732.50657094 5375932.33453671]
...
[ 547982.18       5379959.35      ]
[ 548022.20289132 5379995.794707  ]
[ 548028.26       5379995.52      ]]
Segments: [[    0     2]
[    2     3]
[    3     1]
...
[23905 23904]
[23904 23906]
[23907 23907]]
Length Segments: 23908
Length Vertices: 23908



I honestly don't know what's going on I'm afraid. I wonder if it would be worth raising a GitHub issue.
